# Converting Word to Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a training document to be prepared.I have 132 screenshots in a word document.I want to convert into a PPT.I am using Office 2010.I tried Send To PPT option which opened a blank PPT with 132 slides.I tried to directly open the word doc in Powerpoint again same case.Any help here?

Answer (score 2):

You can import a set of pictures from a folder in Powerpoint by selecting Insert -> Photo Album.

To get your images into a folder for importing into Powerpoint, you can save your Word document as a web page: this will give you one file with the name of your document along with a folder with the same name (less the extension) containing your images.